# Is there a lazy and iterative `map` in Julia?

Tags: julia

The `map` function seems eager, e.g.

`map(x->x+1, 1:3)` gives one `[2,3,4]`.

I want to find a lazy and iterative version of `map` so that the values are not generated all at once, so I can just get values one by one from the result of the `map`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Base.Generator` for this, e.g. in your case:

```
julia> g = (x + 1 for x in 1:3)
Base.Generator{UnitRange{Int64},getfield(Main, Symbol("##5#6"))}(getfield(Main, Symbol("##5#6"))(), 1:3)

julia> collect(g)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 3
 4
```